# RTLabel is not visible as option for Custom Class in Identity Inspector

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard

I can use this class in Code without problem and I have it imported in bridging header...

Is there anyone with same issue?
What i do possibly wrong?

Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "RTLabel.h"
```